# querying how many weeks between a date range and showing them their dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to count how many weeks and listing them up in a table with their respective date range.

so what i have for now is

```
select countinous_weeks, decode(countinous_weeks-52,0,trunc(countinous_weeks),trunc(countinous_weeks)+1)
from (
select (TO_DATE('01-01-1995', 'DD/MM/YYYY') - TO_DATE('01-01-1994','DD/MM/YYYY'))/7 countinous_weeks
from dual) wks
```

it only shows how many weeks within that range. What im aiming to do is showing them up in 53 rows and showing the date range for each week. So lets say for the week one

```
WEEK RANGE
1    01-01-1994 Until 07-01-1994 ... etc
```

Please help me with this query.. much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting. It has got the following things involved -

1. **DATE ROW GENERATOR**
2. **Week number**
3. **ROW_NUMBER()** to assign rank to dates in each set of week
4. Finally **LISTAGG** to aggregate the rows fetched from step 3

Let's see it working -

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT to_date('01/01/1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY') date1,
  3      to_date('31/12/1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY') date2
  4    FROM dual
  5    )
  6  SELECT the_week,
  7    listagg(the_date, ' until ') within GROUP (
  8  ORDER BY to_date(the_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) the_date_range
  9  FROM
 10    (SELECT the_week,
 11      the_date,
 12      row_number() over(partition BY the_week order by the_week, to_date(the_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) rn
 13    FROM
 14      (SELECT TO_CHAR(date1+level-1, 'WW') the_week ,
 15        TO_CHAR(date1      +level-1, 'DD/MM/YYYY') the_date
 16      FROM data
 17        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date2-date1+1
 18      )
 19    )
 20  WHERE rn in( 1, 7)
 21  GROUP BY the_week
 22  /

TH THE_DATE_RANGE
-- ---------------------------------------------
01 01/01/1994 until 07/01/1994
02 08/01/1994 until 14/01/1994
03 15/01/1994 until 21/01/1994
04 22/01/1994 until 28/01/1994
05 29/01/1994 until 04/02/1994
06 05/02/1994 until 11/02/1994
07 12/02/1994 until 18/02/1994
08 19/02/1994 until 25/02/1994
09 26/02/1994 until 04/03/1994
10 05/03/1994 until 11/03/1994
11 12/03/1994 until 18/03/1994
12 19/03/1994 until 25/03/1994
13 26/03/1994 until 01/04/1994
14 02/04/1994 until 08/04/1994
15 09/04/1994 until 15/04/1994
16 16/04/1994 until 22/04/1994
17 23/04/1994 until 29/04/1994
18 30/04/1994 until 06/05/1994
19 07/05/1994 until 13/05/1994
20 14/05/1994 until 20/05/1994
21 21/05/1994 until 27/05/1994
22 28/05/1994 until 03/06/1994
23 04/06/1994 until 10/06/1994
24 11/06/1994 until 17/06/1994
25 18/06/1994 until 24/06/1994
26 25/06/1994 until 01/07/1994
27 02/07/1994 until 08/07/1994
28 09/07/1994 until 15/07/1994
29 16/07/1994 until 22/07/1994
30 23/07/1994 until 29/07/1994
31 30/07/1994 until 05/08/1994
32 06/08/1994 until 12/08/1994
33 13/08/1994 until 19/08/1994
34 20/08/1994 until 26/08/1994
35 27/08/1994 until 02/09/1994
36 03/09/1994 until 09/09/1994
37 10/09/1994 until 16/09/1994
38 17/09/1994 until 23/09/1994
39 24/09/1994 until 30/09/1994
40 01/10/1994 until 07/10/1994
41 08/10/1994 until 14/10/1994
42 15/10/1994 until 21/10/1994
43 22/10/1994 until 28/10/1994
44 29/10/1994 until 04/11/1994
45 05/11/1994 until 11/11/1994
46 12/11/1994 until 18/11/1994
47 19/11/1994 until 25/11/1994
48 26/11/1994 until 02/12/1994
49 03/12/1994 until 09/12/1994
50 10/12/1994 until 16/12/1994
51 17/12/1994 until 23/12/1994
52 24/12/1994 until 30/12/1994
53 31/12/1994

53 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: yet i still have an error lalit ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Thanks. Check if there are any copy paste error. Or else, edit your question and show your sqlplus session.

Comment: i did check but there was no copy paste error. i checked character by character

Comment: Can you please post it. And which tool are you using to execute the query? Is it SQL*Plus or any GUI based tool like SQL Developer, TOAD? Try using a semi-colon instead of slash in the end.

Comment: Your Script has a bug: Why would you want to sort by TO_DATE(DD/MM/YYYY) ??? This will sort 04-FEB-1994 before 29-JAN-1994. And you see in your Row 5 the dates are in the wrong order!

Comment: Not sure why, but it works perfectly for me in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer. I don't have TOAD, but I wonder what could be the issue. I hope your Oracle version supports WITH clause, however, ORA-00923 shouldn't be the error in such case.

Comment: @Falco, Actually the `TO_DATE(the_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')` in the analytic function is correct. It is issue with the `ORDER BY the_Date` in `LISTAGG `aggregation. It should also be `TO_DATE(the_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`. By the way, thanks for pointing it, it needs correction somewhere else. Fixed it.

Comment: @LalitKumarB You could also just leave the_date as an actual date-type (instead of converting it to_char) and just convert it in the LISTAGG, this would make it clearer to read and a little faster (less conversions) - because now you start with a date, convert it to char and convert it back for partitioning and ordering...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query.

```
SELECT LEVEL , to_char( TO_DATE('01-01-1995', 'DD/MM/YYYY') + ( level * 7 ) - 7)  || ' until ' ||  to_char( TO_DATE('01-01-1995', 'DD/MM/YYYY') + ( level * 7 ) - 1 ) as range
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ( select (TO_DATE('01-01-1995', 'DD/MM/YYYY') - TO_DATE('01-01-1994','DD/MM/YYYY'))/7 countinous_weeks
from dual )
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I think I will have to hit you for this: `TO_DATE('01-01-1995', 'DD/MM/YYYY')` If you provide a Date format use the one you actually provide!!! -> DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: This is an incomplete solution. Level and week number cannot be considered same as required output. The last week will always be missed out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - here another solution which I find a bit easier to read:

```
SELECT LEVEL  running_number
      ,TO_CHAR( start_date + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7, 'WW' ) iso_date_week_number
      ,TO_CHAR( start_date + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7, 'DD-MM-YYYY' )
    || ' until '
    || TO_CHAR( start_date + ( LEVEL ) * 7, 'DD-MM-YYYY' )
  FROM
  ( SELECT TO_DATE('01-01-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY') start_date
          ,TO_DATE('01-01-1995', 'DD-MM-YYYY') end_date
      FROM DUAL
  )
CONNECT BY start_date + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7 < end_date;
```

I use connect by and for each Level I add 7 days, until I have reached the end date.